# Melting Temperature of DNA

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to understand the effect of length on the melting temperature of DNA. How can the melting temperature increase if the length increases? Isn't the melting point an intrinsic property?

My attempt to reason it was that DNA melting is actually denaturation and it isn't really melting. However it is still a change in phase so I don't understand why temperature increases with more base pairs.

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track - when biologists say DNA "melts" they mean it denatures. Since DNA is a single molecule (okay, two connected molecules), albeit a large one, it doesn't really make sense to talk about its phase. Consider a single molecule of water: there's no way to tell whether that single molecule is a solid, liquid, or gas.

When we talk about DNA denaturation, what we mean is that every hydrogen bond between the two strands has been broken. The more hydrogen bonds there are to break, the harder this process becomes. DNA strand length is proportional to the number of h-bonds that need to be broken, so a longer strand is harder to denature (or "melt").

Comment: Thank you for your response, a follow up question would be why does the effect of length eventually become negligent? For large DNA strands the melting point eventually peaks out. If there are more hydrogen bonds, shouldn't the temperature increase linearly?

Comment: Huh. I'm actually not sure why that would be the case, and I haven't found any sources supporting that idea in my quick Google searches. This website treats it as a linear function: http://www.austincc.edu/mlt/mdfund/mdfund_unit9assignmentsMeltingTemperature.html

Comment: Yes for short strands.. but when you reach longer strands there is a correction term and no one seems to be able to explain why.

Comment: @DylanPatel Source? I'd love to read more.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_thermodynamics http://www.biology.arizona.edu/biomath/tutorials/linear/linearfunctionapplication/dnamelt.html